# Can I run Appengine apps without the goapp tool/builder?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm wondering if there is any way to run and test GAE Go apps using the standard go test || go build etc tools and if it's not possible what's the technical reason.

Answer (score 2):

The Go App Engine SDK contains the standard Go packages and tools, but a modified version of them.

The GAE SDK also contains local versions of the GAE platform services API implementations which are not part of the SDK (not even the API). So you can't just use the standard Go SDK. When you build or test with the GAE SDK, the SDK takes care of a context mockup so your app will have everything (or most of the things) required to "feel" it is running in the GAE environment. The SDK also contains the sandbox restrictions that are in effect in the production environment (e.g. you can't write to local files).

Also note that some features of the GAE SDK also rely on a Python runtime (because the Go GAE SDK was created using the existing Python GAE SDK), not everything is rewritten in go.

So taking all these into consideration it would not be feasible to build/test using the standard Go SDK and it is not even possible.